# R package CMD check

Tags: r

I have written some codes in R for my personal use. The package successfully installed on my personal laptop (where I have written those commands) and working correctly. But when I distributed it to my other colleagues, this package is not installing and returned these errors.

In R CMD INSTALL

```
Warning in install.packages : running command

"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program

Files\R\R-3.4.3\library" "E:/test/Gene_1.0.tar.gz"' had status 1

Warning in install.packages :   installation of package

E:/test/Gene_1.0.tar.gz had non-zero exit status
```

Secondly, I ran "CHECK PACKAGE" command in R-studio. Those results expressed two errors and two notes.

```
> checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... WARNING
  Dependence on R version '3.5.1' not with patchlevel 0

> checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
   WARNING
  'qpdf' is needed for checks on size reduction of PDFs
0 errors v | 2 warnings x | 2 notes x

Error: R CMD check found WARNINGs

Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Comment: Those are just warnings and not errors. I see one problem here that you're using local file `E:/test/Gene_1.0.tar.gz` which might not be accessible for other users and R is complaining. It's hard to help you without seeing actual code.

Comment: This is not enough information. How did you distribute the package (as source, or built)? I would suggest that you host the code on a version control system such as github.com or gitlab.com. Your colleagues can then easily install the package using devtools::install_git and we can easily spot the issues looking at the code.

Comment: possible issues with spaces in path names?